Using 'showProjectPropertiesDialog' method of QgsInterface to open 'Project Variables' page
I'm trying to open the Project Properties window on the "Variables" page, using pyqgis.

The docs mention that a currentPage string parameter can be passed to QgsInterface.showProjectPropertiesDialog()
Using the following code, I can open the project properties window, but the currentPage parameter only works for "Terrain" and "Sensors". Passing any of "CRS", "Elevation", "General", "Macros", "Metadata", "Settings", "Styles", "Temporal", "Transformations" or, most importantly in my case, "Variables", only opens the window to the most recently opened page... Anybody know what the correct page names are?
from qgis.utils import iface
#iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog("Terrain") # this will open on Terrain page
iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog("Variables") # this opens on whatever was the last page


For the variables page the following works:
iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog(currentPage='mTab_Variables')

By searching the source code, I found the other page names in qgsprojectpropertiesbase.ui
The full list of tab names is below:
iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog(currentPage='mProjOptsGeneral')
iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog(currentPage='mMetadataPage')
iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog(currentPage='mViewSettingsPage')
iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog(currentPage='mProjOptsCRS')
iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog(currentPage='mProjTransformations')
iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog(currentPage='mTab_DataSources')
iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog(currentPage='mTabRelations')
iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog(currentPage='mTab_Variables')
iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog(currentPage='mProjOptsMacros')
iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog(currentPage='mProjOptsOWS')
iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog(currentPage='mTemporalOptions')
iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog(currentPage='Terrain')
iface.showProjectPropertiesDialog(currentPage='Sensors')

